# In Ubuntu 20.04 is it possible to show only custom menu entries in grub?

Tags: grub2, 20.04

Is it possible that grub shows only the menu entries from `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`?

If `yes`, how? Thx.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

Comment: If you write this as an answer I'll accept it. Thx for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus it states the following to only use the custom menus in GRUB:

> **Using Only a Custom Menu**
>
> The following is one example of a way to use only a custom menu and
> not receive any automatic menuentry updates:
>
> ```
> Copy/paste the entire contents of your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file into the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file, below the existing header lines.
>
>     #!/bin/sh
>
>     exec tail -n +3 $0
>
>     # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries. Simply type the
>
>     # menu entries you want to add after this comment. Be careful not to change
>
>     # the 'exec tail' line above.
>
> Remove everything above the first menuentry except the existing header lines above.
>
> Remove all but the following files from the /etc/grub.d folder:
>
>     00_header, 05_debian_theme, 40_custom and README.
>
>     Alternatively, you may keep other files in the /etc/grub.d folder if you make them unexecutable. 
> Edit, add, or remove menuentries as desired, then save the file.
>
> Run update-grub as root to apply the changes!
> ```

Hope this helps!